# Plot IBD family analysis in 23andme style

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I want to create a ggplot for an IBD pedigree analysis  (parents/child/siblings) which looks similar to the 23andme produces.  I was able to use their IBD phasing algorithm to produce data exemplary for chromosome 20 and some family with ID `745` from the 1000 genome HG38 extendend dataset. The results can be found below as object `IBD`.The object `chrom_sizes` gives the length of each chromosome. And the object `centromeres` gives the start and end position of each chromosome as a reference.

The plot of 23andme looks like the following [image]

```
    IBD <- tibble(id1 = c(745,745,745,745),
                  id2 = c(867,1418,1347,1231),
                  id1_hap =c(1,1,1,0),
                  id2_hap =c(1,1,0,1),
                  start=c(1903935, 1917538, 1889345, 1843475),
                  end=c(1944167, 1943602, 1940182, 1940162 ),
                  start_cm=c(10.7, 10.8, 10.5, 9.84),
                  end_cm=c(13.8, 13.8, 13.5, 13.5),
                  start_bd=c(10676547, 10794199, 10480974, 9836741),
                  end_bd=c(13839018, 13824389, 13519497, 13518939),
                  chromosome = c(20, 20, 20, 20)
                  )
chrom_sizes <- structure(list(chromosome = c("chrM", "chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4", 
                                             "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", "chr12", 
                                             "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", "chr17", "chr18", "chr19", 
                                             "chr20", "chr21", "chr22", "chrX", "chrY"),
                              size = c(248956422L, 242193529L, 198295559L, 190214555L, 181538259L,
                                       170805979L, 159345973L, 145138636L, 138394717L, 133797422L,
                                       135086622L, 133275309L, 114364328L, 107043718L, 101991189L,
                                       90338345L, 83257441L, 80373285L, 58617616L, 64444167L, 46709983L,
                                       50818468L, 156040895L, 57227415L, 16569L)),
                         .Names = c("chromosome","size"),
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))

# hg19 centromere locations
centromeres <- structure(list(chromosome = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4", 
                                             "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chrX", "chrY", "chr10", 
                                             "chr11", "chr12", "chr13", "chr14", "chr15", "chr16", "chr17", 
                                             "chr18", "chr19", "chr20", "chr21", "chr22"),
                              start = c(121535434L, 92326171L, 90504854L, 49660117L, 46405641L, 58830166L,
                                        58054331L, 43838887L, 47367679L, 58632012L, 10104553L, 39254935L, 51644205L,
                                        34856694L, 16000000L, 16000000L, 17000000L, 35335801L, 22263006L,
                                        15460898L, 24681782L, 26369569L, 11288129L, 13000000L),
                              end = c(124535434L,95326171L, 93504854L, 52660117L, 49405641L, 61830166L,
                                      61054331L,  46838887L, 50367679L, 61632012L, 13104553L, 42254935L,
                                      54644205L,  37856694L, 19000000L, 19000000L, 20000000L, 38335801L,
                                      25263006L,  18460898L, 27681782L, 29369569L, 14288129L, 16000000L)),
                         .Names = c("chromosome","start", "end"),
                         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I'm aware that my data only contains overlap for the chromosome 20 but I would love to get an outline for all other chromosomes aswell despite the bars would be appear without filled in values.

**Q: How can one create IBD anylsis plots in the style 23andme produces them?**

Comment: Are you asking about the rounded caps? Or the hatched filling? The rest is “just” `geom_segment`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Konrad mentions, it's mostly `geom_segment`s. To get you started, here is a way that it could work, though I was unsure which part of your data to use as colour.

```r
# Data construction same as in question, omitted for brevity

ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    data = chrom_sizes,
    aes(x = 0, xend = size, y = chromosome, yend = chromosome),
    linewidth = 4, lineend = "round", colour = "grey75"
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = centromeres,
    aes(x = start, xend = end, y = chromosome, yend = chromosome),
    linewidth = 4, colour = "grey85"
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = IBD,
    aes(
      x = start_bd, xend = end_bd,
      y = paste0("chr", chromosome), yend = paste0("chr", chromosome),
      colour = id1_hap == id2_hap
    ),
    linewidth = 4
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    limits = unique(chrom_sizes$chromosome)
  )
```

[image]

You can also use `limits = rev(unique(chrom_sizes$chromosome))` to change the sorting of chromosomes.

As an aside, I think you'd want to double check your data because it seems implausible to me that any organism has such a huge mitochondrial genome. Moreover, according to your data, the centromere of the Y chromosome falls outside the bounds of the chromosome, which seems unlikely to me.

Comment: Thanks so far! I wouid like to plot the overlap so the overlap area of start_cm and end_cm of each individual of the family. E.g. compare individual `867` and `1418` for `chr 20`.  Than there would be an overlap between `1917538` cm  and `1943602` cm.

Comment: I guess this can be done by adjusting `geom_segment(
    data = IBD,
    aes(
      x = start_bd, xend = end_bd,
      y = paste0("chr", chromosome), yend = paste0("chr", chromosome),
      colour = id1_hap == id2_hap
    ),
    linewidth = 4
  )` with `colour = as.factor(id2)`

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that might work. Though I too work with genomic data, I'm not at all familiar with hereditary data, so I can't tell you what is right or wrong with that. I just know that you shouldn't fix basepair and centimorgan measures of distance.

Comment: Done. I used the `rCGH` pacakge from the `Biocmanager` to make sure all the measurments are correct!